# run method after the other method is finished delayed job rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem for run methods with delay.

I want run first a method and when this first method is finished run the second method.

1º method

```
Order.delay(queue: "Job", priority: 1, run_at: job.minutes_to_in_progress_overtime.minute.from_now).inprogress_overtime(job)
```

2º Method

```
Order.delay(queue: "Job", priority: 1, run_at: job.minutes_to_cancel_due_to_overtime.minute.from_now).canceled_overtime(job)
```

Here go my class Order:

```
class Order

  def self.inprogress_overtime(job)
   #actions goes here
  end

  def self.canceled_overtime(job)
   #actions goes here
  end

 end
```

How can can I do it?

Thank you ver much!

Comment: I haven't tried it, but could your first method be the one that sets up the second method at the end of it?

Comment: Thank you @MrDanA Can you write a example? Thank you!

Comment: from inside your `inprogress_overtime` method - add the code from `2º Method` above?

Comment: Sorry but it does not work fine for me :(. I have added methods of my model Oder. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on what you are asking, I think it is as simple as this?

```
# enqueue the inprogress_overtime
Order.delay(queue: "Job", priority: 1, run_at: job.minutes_to_in_progress_overtime.minute.from_now).inprogress_overtime(job)

class Order

  def self.inprogress_overtime(job)
    # actions goes here

    # now enqueue the canceled_overtime
    Order.delay(queue: "Job", priority: 1, run_at: job.minutes_to_cancel_due_to_overtime.minute.from_now).canceled_overtime(job)
  end

  def self.canceled_overtime(job)
    # actions goes here
  end

end
```

NOTE: delaying from inprogress_overtime might not be needed, since you are already running in the background job at that point?